# Memory allocation with storage manager leads to not pure function (RM 13.1(22))

Tags: ada, allocation, gnat

Porting some old code to a newer CentOs Linux machine.
I am using linux gnat with a couple of flags:

```
Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-fstack-check", "-g", "-gnatVr", "-gnato", "-gnatE", "-gnatwmuv", "-gnata", "-m32");
```

and I have the gnat version:

```
gcc-gnat.i686   4.8.5-11.el7
```

So these are the preconditions.
I have now an for sure working self-written storage manager which is called by

```
St_Wa.Alloc(StoragePool, BitSize)
```

So now to my problem and to be honest I do not really get the point why the compiler is failing, so I would be really grateful for a detailed explanation why it is not working!

```
function AllocMem(StoragePool : in St_Wa.Mem_Pool_Type;
                  Option: in Option_Type) 
                  return Option_Ref is

 subtype New_Type is Option_Type (Option.Kind);

 New_Option : New_Type;

for New_Option use at St_Wa.Alloc( StoragePool => StoragePool, 
                                    BitSize => New_Type'Size)
begin 
    Bl_Bl.Move( ... sth happens here ... )
    return Pointer(New_Option'Address);
end AllocMem;
```

Whereas:

```
type Option_Type ( Kind : Option_Kind_Type := Marker) is
record
  Next : Option_Ref;
  case Kind is
    when First_Procedure => First_Procedure : First_Procedure_Type;
    when Sec_Procedure => Sec_Procedure : Sec_Procedure_Type;
  end case;
end record;
```

And I get the following Error:

```
invalid address clause for initialized object "New_Option"
function "Alloc" is not pure (RM 13.1 (22))
```

Do I get this error because I have a switch case in the type with conditions and therefore the size is only determined depending on kind? How can I avoid this without rewriting everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I get this error because I have a switch case in the type with conditions and therefore the size is only determined depending on kind?

No. The paragraph referenced by the error message (RM 13.1 (22)) in the LRM reads:

> An implementation need not support representation items containing nonstatic expressions, except that an implementation should support a representation item for a given entity if each nonstatic expression in the representation item is a name that statically denotes a constant declared before the entity.

Now, the representation item here is the call to `Alloc` since your code:

```
for New_Option use at St_Wa.Alloc(StoragePool => StoragePool, 
                                  BitSize => New_Type'Size);
```

is Ada83-style for

```
for New_Option'Address use St_Wa.Alloc(StoragePool => StoragePool, 
                                       BitSize => New_Type'Size);
```

And since `Alloc (...)` is a function call, it is not a static expression, since static functions are, according to RM 4.9:

> - a predefined operator whose parameter and result types are all scalar types none of which are descendants of formal scalar types;
> - a predefined concatenation operator whose result type is a string type;
> - an enumeration literal;
> - a language-defined attribute that is a function, if the prefix denotes a static scalar subtype, and if the parameter and result types are scalar.

Since `Alloc` is none of the above, as RM 13.1 states, the implementation does not need to support it in the representation item. However, the actual error message tells us that *"Alloc" is not pure*, so GNAT tells it it would support this if `Alloc` was pure.

So one way to fix this would be to make `Alloc` pure, which means: Add `pragma Pure;` to the package `St_Wa`, which contains `Alloc`. Whether this is possible depends on the package and it might require additional changes.

If this is not feasible, RM 13.1 (22) hints at another way: A nonstatic expression should be supported if it denotes a constant declared before the entity. Thus, this should work:

```
My_Address : constant System.Address :=
  St_Wa.Alloc(StoragePool => StoragePool, BitSize => New_Type'Size);

New_Option : New_Type;

for New_Option use at My_Address;
```

Comment: I implemented now the second suggestion and get the following warning:
`warning: default initialization of "New_Option" may modify overlaid storage`
`warning: use pragma Import for "New_Option" to suppress initialization (RM B.1(24)) `
But at least now it is compiling , thanks for the support , I was not able to see the fact that not pure is affecting the function call

Comment: That warning can be fixed with `pragma Import (New_Option);`. Reason is that your record (judging from the type names) contains function pointers, and those get initialized with `null` upon variable declaration. However, you may not want that to happen since `Alloc` may have done initialization.